# WSO2MB doesnot work in spring boot

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

I am trying to use WSO2MB in spring boot, but the maven is not able to download the dependencies like andes-client-3.1.1.jar.

It is working fine when I use msf4j. Is it not possible for spring-boot to use wso2mb?

I am getting error:
Failure to find org.wso2.andes.wso2:andes-client:jar:0.13.wso2v10 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those artifacts are not synced with the maven central. You can add the wso2 nexus as a repository in the pom.
http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/